# Forcing sklearn cross val score to use stratified k fold?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-fold

Based on [Sklearn Docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score):

- Is it possible to force the use of `StratifiedKFold`?
- How can I know which `KFold` has been used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this:

```
 cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, cv=YOURCHOICE)
```

Example:

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

X = diabetes.data[:150]
y = diabetes.target[:150]
lasso = linear_model.Lasso()

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2)
results = cross_val_score(lasso, X, y, cv=skf)
```

Comment: and how do you check if it is the method I wanted

Comment: you cannot explicitly check this but it is guaranteed by the source code internally

Answer (score 0):

in the [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) wrote that:

> "For `int`/`None` inputs, if the estimator is a classifier and `y` is either binary or
> multiclass, `StratifiedKFold` is used. In all other cases, `KFold` is
> used."...

If your model is a classifier, just use an integer for using `StratifiedKFold`.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30621448)